# How to use libpqxx with qt creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, libpqxx

I use Ubuntu 18.04, Qt creator 4.5.2. I added in pro file:

```
CONFIG += c++1z
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -lpq -lpqxx
```

Still got following error:

```
 /usr/local/include/pqxx/strconv.hxx:76: error: undefined reference to `pqxx::internal::demangle_type_name[abi:cxx11](char const*)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-lpq -lpqxx` are linker flags. The variable `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` specifies compiler flags. Use the proper variable `QMAKE_LIBS` for specifying linker flags:

```
LIBS += -lpq -lpqxx
```